# Why am I getting garbage value instead of RGB while printing out colour of pixels in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, pixel, mat

This snippet of code prints out garbage values.

```
cv::Mat_<cv::vec3b>::iterator it = img.begin<cv::vec3b>(),
itEnd = img.end<cv::vec3b>();

for(; it != itEnd; ++it)
   std::cout << (*it)[1] << std::endl;
```

But this prints out the vector of RGB values.

> std::cout << img.at(100,200);

The moment I try to access the individual RGB values I get garbage values printed,

Any reason why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about OpenCV but if each of your element in vector is of format say [221,123,321], then individually splitting string based on ',' seperator you can retrieve individual pixel values.

What i understand is this:

```
 #include<sstream>

 string buf;

 cout<<"Printing elements:"<<endl;

 for(unsigned i=0;i<img.size();i++)
 {
   istringstream is(img[i]);

   while(getline(is, buf, ','))
   {
     if(buf.at(0)=='[')
     {
       buf.erase(0, 1);
     }
     if(buf.at(buf.length()-1)==']')
     {
       buf.erase(buf.length()-1, buf.length());
     }
     cout<<buf<<endl;
   }  
 }
```

**OUTPUT**

Printing elements:

221

123

321

...

...

Comment: I am getting the triplet of pixel values correctly. For example *it prints 
...
[203, 208, 209]
[205, 209, 210]...

When I want to access the RGB colours separately by doing (*it).val[0] i am getting � and other weird characters.

Comment: @web_ninja try cast to int `int((*it).val[0])` when printing.

Comment: @Kiro This worked. I had done the error of storing the type casted value in uchar. Which printed the ascii equivalent of the int.